# JVC Everio GZ-MS90E aspect ratio is 5:4 instead of 16:9

Tags: premiere

I am working with an JVC Everio GZ-MS90E which is configured to produce a 16:9 video. But my aspect ratio is 5:4 instead of 16:9.

Width: 720
Height: 576

Width/Height = aspect ratio
720/576 = 1.25 = 5:4

Does anybody have similar problems or probably a solution how to fix that?

I am really annoyed because I don't know the right preset for my Adobe Premiere Pro CS5.5 sequence. I have already some clips and I would like to use them without transcoding.

Comment: Your video is 16:9, you just need to create a sequence at widescreen square pixel (1024x576, P/A of 1.0). If you drop the footage on that sequence it should appear 'correctly'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the right way for my footage. It was simple: Just right click on the footage, and select **Ändern » Filmmaterial interpretieren**. This is probably **Change » Footage** or something like that.

Then I fored premiere to use the aspect ratio **D1/DV PAL Widescreen 16:9** and everything is fine.

Comment: Please select this as the accepted answer so that it will no longer show up in the unanswered questions list.